# Using pygame and making class for a character, keep getting error: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, class

With this code:

```
import pygame

class Creature(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__()

class Human(Creature):

    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('resources/images/Protag.png')

        pygame.draw(self.image)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels
```

I keep getting the error in the title. I followed a tutorial online and still am getting this error. Any ideas why?

Comment: Please add the full exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

In your `Human` class, in the `__init__` function change it to this(for Python 2):

```
super(Human, self).__init__()
```

If you're using Python 3 then:

```
super()
```

Comment: `super()` by itself doesn't do anything.

Comment: I may be wrong but if no parameters are passed to the `__init__` function super works like this. If on the other hand, there are parameters to be passed then this shall work `super().__init__(x, y)`

Comment: @kingJulian In my testing, it does not. If you want to run the parent class's `__init__()` (or any other) method, you need to explicitly call it on the `super()` object regardless of the number of parameters. Feel free to verify with your own testing, though... could be a niche feature somewhere that I've never seen.